# Rounding with PyAudio

Tags: python, fft, pyaudio

I have tried to record a chunk of audio with PyAudio, then perform FFT to get the frequency. However it seems the results are always 'rounded'.
Code:

```
import pyaudio
import struct
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq
import numpy as np


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=44100,
                frames_per_buffer=1024,
                input=True)

while 1:
    data = stream.read(1024)
    data = struct.unpack(str(1024) + 'h', data)

    x = rfftfreq(len(data), 1/44100)
    y = rfft(data)

    print(x[np.argmax(y)])
```

Output when playing A440:

430.6640625

430.6640625

473.73046875

473.73046875

43.06640625

43.06640625

43.06640625

473.73046875

I don't seem to get 440 exactly, and the values stay surprisingly constant after many decimal places.

Comment: Where do you play the A440? Where is the audio coming from?

Comment: I am using a random tone generator website, namely https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/, from my phone